# Callback after multiple asynchronous calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, scope

I'm using the Gmail API to retrieve messages in a loop and do a req.write() for each message. There's a callback for each api invocation, but how do I know when the whole set is done so I can end the response? I tried the following but noticed that the callbacks are not executed in order of array index so I can't just do the line I commented out.

```
for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            var message = messages[i];
            console.log('- %s', message.id);
            (function(e){
              var request = gmail.users.messages.get({
                  auth:auth,
                  id:message.id,
                  userId: 'me'
                }, function(err, response) {
                  if(err) {
                    console.log('API returned an error: ' +err);
                    return;
                  }
                  res.write(JSON.stringify(response,null,'\t'));
                  console.log(e);
                  //if(e==messages.length-1) res.end();
                }
              );
            })(i);
}
```

Comment: Solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799672/node-js-how-to-set-a-variable-outside-the-current-scope/32799727#32799727) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871543/order-of-execution-issue-javascript/32872009#32872009).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, though. Since you won't get *any* callbacks until your loop is completed, you can just keep track of how many callbacks you've gotten and when it reaches messages.length, you know you're done:

```
var completed = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    var message = messages[i];
    console.log('- %s', message.id);
    var request = gmail.users.messages.get({
        auth: auth,
        id: message.id,
        userId: 'me'
    }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            // Should increment and check `completed` here too,
            // not sure what you want to do though
            console.log('API returned an error: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        res.write(JSON.stringify(response, null, '\t'));
        if (++completed == messages.length) {
            res.end();
        }
    });
}
```

That assumes nothing will change `messages` in the meantime (affecting its length). If that assumption isn't valid, you can just invert `completed`, call it `pending`, and you're done when it reaches `0`:

```
var pending = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    var message = messages[i];
    console.log('- %s', message.id);
    var request = gmail.users.messages.get({
        auth: auth,
        id: message.id,
        userId: 'me'
    }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            // Should decrement and check `pending` here too,
            // not sure what you want to do though
            console.log('API returned an error: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        res.write(JSON.stringify(response, null, '\t'));
        if (--pending === 0) {
            res.end();
        }
    });
    ++pending;
}
```