# How to Indent Code in Asynchronous Coffee Script

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express, coffeescript

I have an **indentation** problem in my **Coffee Script**!!

I'm asking myself how put these lines of code so that they run smoothly and don't skip stuff. The impact is that the array **friendsCollection** is empty, when I want to use it in my view.

I guess the problem is coffee script (javascript) itself (because it works asynchronously) but I have no idea how to go about that.

Now, this is the code:

```
app.get '/', (req, res) ->
  brain = req.session
  if brain.userId
    friendsCollection = []
    data.serialize ->
      data.each "select rowid as id, * from friends where userId='#{brain.userId}'", (err, row) ->
        if not err
          if row isnt undefined
            friend =
              name: row.name
              email: row.email
              phone: row.phone
              location: row.location
              relationship: row.relationship
              notes: row.notes
            friendsCollection.push friend
      res.render 'app/index',
        id: brain.userId
        friendsCollection: friendsCollection
  else
    res.render 'notAllowed'
```

I would be happy if someone could fix this code (a little bit)!

Comment: This isn't an indentation problem.  This is an async problem.  You need to not call res.render until all your async operations are complete.  Personally, I'd use a promise-based interface to the database and use `Promise.all()` or Bluebird's `Promise.map()` to know when all the async operations are done and I could then call `res.render()`.

Comment: Thanks, could you provide an conceptual code example ??!

Comment: Multiple examples here for how you accumulate the results of multiple async operations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799672/node-js-how-to-set-a-variable-outside-the-current-scope/32799727#32799727